# getAdapterPosition() is deprecated

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I've updated my `targetSdkVersion` from 28 to 30 and I've noticed that `getAdapterPosition()` is deprecated (I'm not sure when this happened).

In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition()), they say the following:

> This method is deprecated.
> This method is confusing when adapters nest other adapters. If you are calling this in the context of an Adapter, you probably want to call [getBindingAdapterPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getBindingAdapterPosition()) or if you want the position as RecyclerView sees it, you should call [getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()).

The documentation also says the following:

> Note that if you are querying the position as RecyclerView sees, you should use [getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()) (e.g. you want to use it to save scroll state). If you are querying the position to access the RecyclerView.Adapter contents, you should use [getBindingAdapterPosition()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getBindingAdapterPosition()).

How I understand it is:

- `getBindingAdapterPosition` should be used when you want to get the adapter position (if it still exists in the adapter). If it no longer exists in the adapter, it will return `-1`([NO_POSITION](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#NO_POSITION)).
- `getAbsoluteAdapterPosition` should be used to get the position as the `RecyclerView` sees it. For example, if an item has been deleted, but not yet removed from the`ViewHolder`.

In other words, if I have `4` items in my `Adapter`, I delete position `0` and query `getAbsoluteAdapterPosition` and `getBindingAdapterPosition` before the item has been removed from the `ViewHolder`, then `getAbsoluteAdapterPosition` will return `0`(because view is still in the `ViewHolder`) and `getBindingAdapterPosition` return `-1`(Because it no longer exists in the adapter).

---

I have tested the difference by logging the following:

```
Log.e("difference", "getAdapterPosition = "+myHolder.getAdapterPosition()+" getBindingAdapterPosition = "+myHolder.getBindingAdapterPosition()+" getAbsoluteAdapterPosition = "+myHolder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
```

They return exactly the same values. I could not see any difference.

I also see no difference before or after calling `notifyItemChanged`, `notifyDataSetChanged` or `notifyItemRangeChanged`. But when I delete position `0` and call `notifyItemRemoved` it returns `-1` afterward (for all of them).

### My questions

Do I understand this correctly, and when should we be using which? Also, when will there be a difference?

Comment: There is a difference if you use the new **`ConcatAdapter`** introduced in the `1.2.0`. In this case the `getBindingAdapterPosition()` returns the position in the specific adapter and not the whole `ConcatAdapter`. Instead the `getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()` returns the position in the `ConcatAdapter`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Ah that makes sense. So does that mean that, if I have a single adapter, then I can use either  `getBindingAdapterPosition()` or `getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()`, or will there be a difference?

Comment: Also if you check the source code, `getAdapterPosition()` returns now `getBindingAdapterPosition();`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti If you have time, please provide an answer for me to except. I had a look at the source code and as you mentioned, `getAdapterPosition();` get replaced with `getBindingAdapterPosition();`. 
 I think it's safe to say that we should be using `getBindingAdapterPosition();` when we are using a single adapter.

Comment: Personally I think this deprecation was uncalled for. In 98% of cases `ConcatAdapter` won't even be used yet one of the most commonly used method of `ViewHolder` was renamed to account for its existence.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The `recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha02` introduced the `MergeAdapter` that has been renamed to [**`ConcatAdapter`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter) with **`recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha04`**.
This RecyclerView Adapter can combine **multiple adapters** linearly.

Something like:

```
FirstAdapter adapter1 = ...;
SecondAdapter adapter2 = ...;
ConcatAdapter merged = new ConcatAdapter(adapter1, adapter2);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mergedAdapter);
```

As part of this change the method [**`getAdapterPosition()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAdapterPosition()) was deprecated because the name is confusing when adapters nest other adapters. Now you should use the method [**`getBindingAdapterPosition()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getBindingAdapterPosition()) which returns the position in the **specific adapter** (`bindingAdapter`).

Also checking the source code of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`:

```
    @Deprecated
    public final int getAdapterPosition() {
        return getBindingAdapterPosition();
    }
```

Instead the method [**`getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()) returns the Adapter position of the item with respect to the **entire** `RecyclerView`. If you are using a `ConcatAdapter` it is the position in the `ConcatAdapter` and not the position in the single bindingAdapter.

Just an example with 2 adapters:

[image]

More details are available in the [official blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a).

Comment: Does this mean that the binding adapter position is what we need to get the right data from list of model since calling getAdapterPosition now just use getBindingAdapterPosition internally?

Comment: @MihaeKheel yes

Comment: if there is only one adapter, then all the occurrences of `getAdapterPosition` should be changed to `getBindingAdapterPosition`. Right?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Yes

Comment: You can also use getAbsoluteAdapterPosition if you are not using ConcatAdapter.