# Can someone tell me why it gives me an error when I try to use "absoluteAdapterPosition" in a Recycler View in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

It tells me there is a mismatch, it requires "AdapterView<*>! but it has found "Int". How do I fix this?

[image: Error Screenshot]

```
class InstructorViewHolder(itemView: View, listener: OnItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val firstName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvInstructorName)
    val phoneNumber: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvInstructorNumber)
    val age: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvInstructorAge)

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onItemClick(absoluteAdapterPosition)
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to use "bindingAdapterPosition" but still got the same error.
On this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()) it states that the return type should be Int, that why I am confused as to why it is asking me to provide "AdapterView<*>".

I looked at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63068519/getadapterposition-is-deprecated) however, it doesn't exactly explain how to implement the feature.

Comment: Need to see you whole adapter class to be able to tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `listener.onItemClick`, and from that very blurry screenshot it looks like `listener` is an `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`. From [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener):

```
public abstract void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, 
                View view, 
                int position, 
                long id)
```

So the problem isn't `absoluteAdapterPosition` - that's providing an `Int` just fine! But the error is *complaining that you're passing an `Int`* because what it's actually *expecting* is an `AdapterView<*>`. That's what it *required*, but what it *found* was the `Int` you're providing, right? So you can tell where the problem is coming from by the language it's using. (And since that method has a few other parameters, it'll complain about those being missing if you fix this one)

Going by what you're trying to do (call `onItemClick` with a single `Int` parameter) I'm guessing you imported the wrong `OnItemClickListener` - that's often what's happened if you try to use a thing and it looks completely wrong!